# Cannot transpile ES module in Nextjs using next-transpile-modules

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am using deepdash-es in Nextjs but it is a ES module so it keeps showing this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQYK4.png)

I have tried next-transpile-modules but it still not work

Comment: Please copy the error message into a code section of your question. Image links might expire so that your question gets useless for others with the same problem in the future.

Comment: Did you "enabled" this lib in the next-transpile-modules plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried deepdash-es in nextjs example app and it [works fine](https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dawn-jyqh1?file=/pages/index.js)

If you found any bug - please report on [GitHub](https://github.com/YuriGor/deepdash/issues)